# drawing package in tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I just want to learn how to make graphics in TeX. I have looked through this site and tried some TeX source file. But I am confused by the TikZ and tkz packages. Do they have any relation or are they completely different?

In my daily work, I draw 2D graphics. It is about general arrangement of buildings. For example:

```
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

All the lines are axis lines. Columns are placed at the intersection. Beams are placed at all the lines. Beam lines will be offset to both side based on the axis line. For this kind of graphics, which package is the best choice?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 4):

One of the most popular graphics bundles is `PGF`,  which comes with 
a user-friedly syntax layer called `TikZ`. There are also a number of packages that all start with `tkz` as a prefix. For example `tkz-2d`. You can see many examples at [texample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tkz-2d/)

If these are suitable for what you are looking to produce you need to experiment and decide, although for building plans, perhaps you are better off staying with an application such as Autocad and importing pdfs in your TeX/LaTeX document.

Comment: i produce drawing by Autocad(i am good at Autocad very much). on the other hand, i must generate static calculation sheet. for this, i make a front end(by C language) to generate tex source file. in my calculation sheet, there are some graphics. i can make these graphics in Autocad then include them in tex. but i do want to finish all the job in my own front end. this is why i want one graphics package for tex. for tikz and tkz, do they have any relation?

Comment: @warem yes any package with a `tkz` prefix uses `tikz`. For small diagrams like what you want to use in your calculation sheets `tikz` is ideal. Start from http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/.

Comment: @Yiannis Lazarides: does it mean if i install tikz package, i can also use tkz package?

Comment: Better, start by reading the first and third tutorial of the tikz manual (TikZ should already be installed with your TeX distribution). They cover the material that you are most likely to need.

Comment: @warem: Yes, you should be able to use both. However, there is no need to install them by hand. Both are included in recent TeX distributions. Use the package manager of your TeX distribution for installing them (if they aren't already).

Comment: TikZ/PGF is unparalleled.  Check out the http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/.  I suspect you find a good lead for the functionality you need.  (I'm experimenting with Asymptote now, but I believe TikZ better suits your needs.) To echo above comments, I use Perl as a front-end to generate complex figures and charts. It's hard to beat.

Comment: ok. thank all of you. i will try Tikz first.

Comment: @warem I'm the author of the tkz collection, and if you try one package, I can help you but I think it's better to give a look at the pgfmanual or perhaps at something like http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mertz/mertz.pdf  Now tkz is not tikz. This is  based  on TikZ.  A better idea is to try to program with TikZ directly

Comment: @Altermundus to my feeling, i think tkz is different from tikz. you confirm this point. thank you.